# Co-ordinate proximity in a 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-dimensional array of type `Animal` (user defined type). I have the array set up so that it is randomly populated with either a `Prey` or `Pred` of type `Animal` or nothing (it is left `null`).

My question is about **proximity**, I want to know whether a `Prey` is in a space next to a `Pred` (including diagonals). Say I had this:

```
{null, null, null,    
 null, Prey, null,
 Pred, null, null}
```

Assuming I use:

```
Animal[][] grid = new Animal[3][3];
```

If I simply say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <  3; j++){
        if (grid[i+1][j] == Pred || grid[i+1][j+1] == Pred || grid[i+1][j+1] == Pred
        || grid[i][j+1] == Pred || grid[i-1][j+1] == Pred || grid[i+1][j] == Pred
        || grid[i-1][j] == Pred || grid[i-1][j-1]) == Pred) // Then proximity = true.
    }
}
```

**Would this be horribly inefficient?** Would the entire array have to be searched through 8 times to check if the if statement returns true? 
I need to scale up the array to perhaps a few thousand "spaces" and I would like a method that won't take too much time. 
If this way is inefficient, can anybody suggest a better (maybe cleaner) approach?

Comment: this looks like it will throw `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` a lot..

Comment: sionnach733 is right.  looks like any space where j != 1 or i == 0 or i == length will result in an exception.

Comment: also there is a typo in the second for loop, the i should be a j

Comment: looks like you don't check for `Prey` at all.

Comment: Is that because if we are in a space at the boundary of the grid then Java will try to access an element outside of the grid size? I could factor that into the algorithm and test if we a re in  boundary space but I can see the code getting really long!

Comment: @Bennef Code tends to get longer as the algorithm gets more complex.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc :) Of course, my question was "is there a more efficient way to check for proximity?"

Comment: A nice solution to having to repeat edge detection over and over is to pad the arrays by one at each edge.

Comment: Ooh, I like it. That makes sense and I can keep everything simple. Thanks @ChrisK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you'll have to do a `n^2` algorithm if you want to check every possible index in the 2D array.

You want to make sure these 4 conditions are `true` in this priority for every `if` statement:

1. `i+1 < grid.length`
2. `i-1 >= 0`
3. `j+1 < grid[i].length`
4. `j-1 >= 0`

Follow this pseudo code to avoid errors:

```
boolean proximity = false;
for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <  grid[i].length; j++){
        if(grid[i][j] == Pred){  //only care if its a Pred
            //now check for Prey
            //make sure youre not out of bounds!
            if(i+1 < grid.length && grid[i+1][j] == Prey) proximity = true;
            else if(i+1 < grid.length && j+1 < grid[i].length && grid[i+1][j+1] == Prey) proximity = true;
            //do for rest etc.
        }
        if(proximity) break;//once found, youre done.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will use this idea to check for boundary. The Animals are randomly placed so I guess I need to check every space. n^2 it is. Thanks, this has helped me.

Comment: @Bennef:  That's for worse case.  Using `break` as soon as you find `proximity` will help the average case and best case scenario.

Comment: @Bennef:  Another option is to do a check as you randomly generate the `Prey`/`Pred`/`null` into the `grid`.  It'll still be overall worse case scenario of `n^2`, but it'll definitely avoid looping over `grid` again.

Comment: Aha, that would be perfect, apart from the animals randomly move about every update (I am simulating an ecosystem you see)

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use this aproach if many positions are null. You can walk through the matrix from left to right and top-down. Only check the 8 comparations when you found a Pred. Also, as you have looked at current cell when you were checking the previous cell (west) and the cells on the row above (north-west, north and north-east), yo do not need to check the 8 positions, only this four: the East, South-East, South and South-West cells of the current cell if this contains a Pred

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; i <  3; j++){
       if(grid[i][j] == Pred)
       {
          if (grid[i][j+1] == Prey || grid[i+1][j-1] == Prey || grid[i+1][j] == Prey
            || grid[i+1][j+1] == Prey ) // Then proximity = true.
       }
       if(grid[i][j] == Prey)
       {
          if (grid[i][j+1] == Pred || grid[i+1][j-1] == Pred || grid[i+1][j] == Pred
            || grid[i+1][j+1] == Pred ) // Then proximity = true.
       }
    }
}
```

Note the proximity es bilateral, if grid[i][j] has proximity with grid[i+1][j+1], for example, then grid[i+1][j+1] has proximity with grid[i][j].

Also, you must have in mind the matrix's bounds. Don't check de row below if you are in the last, don't check the column on the left if you are on the first column, and don't check the column on the right if you are on the last column. (With this aproach, you are never going to check on the row above so don't worry about the top bound)

Edited and corrected. You also have to note the bilareal proximity.

Comment: This would only work if the last two rows had enough Prey to have checked their 8 surrounding spaces. If I had just one Prey, say near the south-east then I would need to check all 8 directions. (I only check for Prey, THEN for surrounding Predators)

Comment: Ok, right. Then let's do the same for Preys. You are yet saving to check the 8 operations per null cell and 4 operations for the other cells

Answer (score 0):

you could make a function like the following:

```
public boolean containsPreditor(int x, int y, Animal[] grid)
{
    boolean outOfBounds = false;
    if(x < 0 || x >= grid[0].length)
    {
         outOfBounds = true;
    }
    if(y < 0 || y >= grid.length)
    {
         outOfBounds = true;
    }

     if(!outOfBounds)
     {
      return grid[y][x] == Pred;
     }
     else
     {
      //space does not exist
      return false;
     }

}
```

then you could run the method for the 3x3 grid, or however big you want it by modifying the loop size

```
    boolean proximity = false;
    int xIndex; //assign this
    int yIndex; //assign this too
 for(int i = (yIndex - 1); i <= (yIndex + 1); i++)
 {
      for(int j = (xIndex - 1); j <= (xIndex + 1); j++)
       {
          proximity = proximity || containsPreditor(j, i, Animals);
       }
 }
```

Essentially the same thing, but easier to understand and debug

Answer (score 0):

I had a think overnight on this for you, and realized that one can go a lot faster by representing the board as a bit set, and then using bit logic to combine.  This approach is exceptionally CPU and CPU cache friendly, but it does need a bit of upfront computation and ideally a change in how you store the board.  If you cannot do that, then there will be some overhead to overcome.  However it will be worth the effort!

The basic algorithm is:

```
preyAtRisk = bitCount( squaresAtRisk.bitAnd(squaresWithPrey) )
```

This algorithm can be implemented with very few conditional jumps, modern CPUs can perform 64 bit ands in a single cpu cycle and most JVMs provide an intrinsic for Integer.bitCount and Long.bitCount which replaces them with an assembly instruction.  Thus a lot of the looping can be done in parallel, in hardware.   That is, FAST!

This algorithm requires representing the board as a bit set.  So for a 3x3 board, the first square would be the first bit and so on up to the ninth square being the ninth bit.

Thus your example of

```
{null, null, null,    
 null, Prey, null,
 Pred, null, null}
```

would be represented by the following two bit sets

```
prey  = 000 010 000
preds = 000 000 100
```

We then need to convert the preds bit set, into a bitset that represents which squares are at risk.  This can be done by precomputing a bitset of which squares would be at risk for each individual square.  Which would look something like this:

```
dangerZones[0] = 010 110 000
dangerZones[1] = 101 111 000
dangerZones[2] = 010 011 000
...
```

Then as the preds are added to the collection, or in its own iteration squaresAtRisk can be built up:

```
public void setPred( x, y ) {
  bitIndex       = toBitIndex(x,y)
  squaresAtRisk &= dangerZones[bitIndex]
}
```